# Host mirroring or multiple-host for one domain

Tags: web-server, hosting, web-hosting, host

I have already bought a host service from a host provider company but the host service down a lot and they are not good at all. I don't want to fall down in the hell again I like something like server mirroring for my host if one fails another runs quickly what is the best solution? I have seen before some sites have many ns record is that means they are connected to multiple server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than setup mirroring, if you are only worried about uptime your best bet is to switch hosts.  If you have paid for a service already and it is not working I would suggest contacting them.  Maybe they can simply move your site to another server without issues.  If you get nowhere with support and you have already paid them up front for some time of hosting you might be out of luck.

To directly answer your question yes you can have "server mirroring".  A lot of sites employ this through a load balancer or similar technology.  In this scenario the website is pointed at the load balancer and that device can push traffic to several different servers.  There are hardware and software load balancers, and the hardware devices can cost a lot of money.  One of the more popular software solutions is HA Proxy. http://haproxy.1wt.eu/

If you are looking for something more affordable you could also look at round robin DNS.  I believe this is what you mean when you say multiple records for a host.  The downfall to this is that if one of your hosts has issues there is no way to just turn that host off to fix the problem.  In round robin dns a random record is returned and used for that host, and it could be the bad one, even more than 50% of the time.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_DNS

Redundancy can be an expensive and complex task, so I would advise you to use a more reliable web host or look into the many cloud options available.